# How do I add an image to a combo in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I managed to add a images in the extjs combo selection list however after selecting an item did not manage to have the same images displayed int he collapsed combo. I tried changing the template (displayTpl) by adding some custom HTML however it will get escaped. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
   this.chartCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        height: '20',
        fieldLabel: 'Chart Type',
        displayField: 'chartLabel',
        valueField: 'chartValue',
        store: chartComboDataSource,
        queryMode: 'local',
        listConfig: {
            getInnerTpl: function() {
                this.cls = 'option-list-chart-img';
                return "<img class='{cssClassName}'/> {chartLabel}";
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you specified width and height in css class? Try also change display property to block.

Comment: For ExtJS4 see the following answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14434708/1749200

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the collapsed combo is just a simple `<input>` element that can't contain HTML. I suggest you set the image as a background image to the `<input>`, switching it programmatically when selection changes.

Comment: I also tried that however i understand this is not supported in IE, is that right ?